# coevery crm proper installation

Tags: crm

I have downloaded Coevery CRM from it's [github repository](https://github.com/Coevery/Coevery) and installed it.
but it seems that it does not have any modules installed, even the basic ones like Leads,Contacts and other modules or entities.

Here is an screenshot of what I'm talking about:
[image]

As you can see there is no sidebar menus or anything when logged in.

Unfortunately I couldn't find anything to sort out the issue, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same question. The installation is correct, you just have to create your own entities as you have nothing to be shown here. Click on the person image on the right and click admin, then add your entities and perspectives (for navigation).

[This user-guide](https://www.google.com.eg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjx8-LzmuPLAhUDXCwKHcYzBHMQtwIIMzAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D4g1N_P0-5WM&usg=AFQjCNEf7yXwzp5CaaJQh8KwK68oOEU1YA&bvm=bv.117868183,d.bGg) is helpful.